# js one variable can not pass the other variable data

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my code:

```
async function rScript() {
    var dbHost1 = '';
    var dbHost2;
    var DDD = await lineReader.eachLine(file, function(line) {
        if (line.includes('DB_HOST')) {
            dbHost2 = line.substr(18, 11);
            console.log('dbHost2', dbHost2);
            dbHost1 = dbHost2;
        }
    });
    console.log('DDD', DDD)
    console.log('dbHost1', dbHost1);
}
```

result:

```
DDD { getReader: [Function: getReader] }
dbHost1
dbHost2 'localhost'
```

Here i set dbHost1 value as dbHost2 data but its not getting the data from dbHost2 ? whats the problem in my code?

Comment: Looks like the `await` doesn't do what you think it does. What is `lineReader.eachLine()`? What made you assume it returns a promise?

Comment: yes it returns a promise

Comment: Then why does that promise resolve before the callback is executed? Makes no sense.

Comment: so that how to fix this? is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Well what exactly did you intend to do? Read lines until you found one starting with `DB_HOST`? Read all lines? Also it's not quite clear why you used two separate `dbHost` variables to begin with.